# Tool for converting subset of PHP code into Java/Scala/Groovy?

Tags: java, php, scala

Do any exist? Ideally it would also come with a library of basic PHP functions.

I have a bunch of simple PHP scripts (no extensions, no fancy dynamic hacks, etc) I'd like to convert to Java... It would be great if a tool could do 80% of the work while I do the other 20%.

Comment: @Alex R: I would look at the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/363805/what-is-the-best-way-to-convert-an-existing-php-class-into-java

Comment: That was a non-answer, saying you should do it 100% by hand. I don't believe in that. A tool should do 80% of the work.

Comment: The other question asked for the "best way", I'm just asking for "a tool" :-)

Answer (score 3):

It seems you're just after running some PHP on JVM. You could try out one of these: [Project Zero](https://www.projectzero.org/php/) or [Quercus](http://www.caucho.com/resin-3.0/quercus/)

Comment: No, running PHP on the JVM would mean keeping the PHP. I want to throw out... discard... delete... all PHP code!

I was hoping for something a bit more elaborated than this quick hack:
http://www.incogen.com/downloads/phpToJava.pl